# Google sheets query returning #VALUE! error

Tags: google-sheets

I am having problems with a query that is returning #VALUE! This query works perfectly:

```
=Query(importrange(D2,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"select Col2 Where Col3 = '"&A73&"'", 0)
```

where this query doesn't:

```
=Query(importrange(D2,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"select Col2 Where Col3 = '"&A74&"'", 0)
```

From what I can see they are the same, the only difference being the A73 and A74 cell reference. What am I not seeing? Any help would be great.

Comment: I can't, it's a work related project. It's basically a parts list where A74 is a part name and I'm trying to get the matching part number. D2 references the address to a separate spreadsheet. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: check the formatting of cell A74 if its not different from A73

Answer (score 0):

if the first `QUERY` works for you and the 2nd one is not it's probably due to formatting. click on <kbd>123</kbd> button and check formatting for both cells. if the error persists check if `Col3` has such value listed in **A74** cell.

[image: 0]

Comment: I did figure it out. The part number had a trailing '' added to the part name and the query was seeing it as a ' '. My answer to it was to use a like statement and all is good now.